# how to make desktop fit the physical screen

Tags: display-resolution

Toshiba Satellite C50-B, Lubuntu 18.04.

Since 18.04, when the laptop is booting there are light blue lines at the top and bottom of the screen, about 4 pixels thick.
When running with application maximized, the small gap is still there.

**xrandr** is so complicated I can't understand it.
**lxrandr** only says what its got: eDP-1: 1366x768  60 fps
**arandr** doesn't say how to use it.

How can I make the "desktop area" fill the physical screen?

Comment: 1366x768 is the maximum resolution that monitor supports.  Could you maybe take a pic or screen shot and show us what you are seeing?

Comment: I could, but you probably wouldn't be able to see the difference.  A maximized window appears to be positioned at line 4 and ends at line 1362.  It needs to be stretched vertically to fill the screen.

Comment: Error, sorry - line 4  to line 764.